# Redirect to a dynamic controller in Laravel from a controller

Tags: laravel-5

I have a controller that maps the route `/print/{car}` let's call him `IndexController`

I want that according to the type of object to redirect the proper Controller. For each type of car I have a different controller: `SportCarController`, `TruckController`, `FamilyCarController` each controller, leading to separate 'wizard steps'.  How can I have an elegant way of doing (pseudo-code)

```
function index(($carInstance){
     $goodController = GetMeGoodController:factory($carInsantce);
     redirectTo($goodController,'index');//where index is the method
 }
```

PS1: Having different routes is not feasible as adding new types for this object should not change the route. Also changing the type of an object should not interfere with the route. When i refer to `redirecTo` i am talking about redirect to another controller action, and not HTTP redirect.

Comment: why must you redirect. why not create route for each controller. please make you question clearer

Comment: I hope I answered to your comment with PS1.